# Azure timer-triggered function does not work with certain cron expressions

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have created an Azure timer trigger function with cron expression `*/30 * * * * *` and as soon as I changes the expression to `0 */1 * * * *`, I get this error:

> The listener for function  was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor.

This is how my function class looks like

```
public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting doesn't look like it's an error that is being thrown because of the CRON expression. If you're running the Function locally, please make sure a Storage Emulator (like Azurite) is running and the Function App is configured to connect to that emulator. This error seems to indicate the Functions Runtime.

More info: [Use the Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite).

### OFF-TOPIC

An asterisk (*) means 'every'. An asterisk divided by a number X means 'every X'.

The `*/1` for minutes (which would be the same as `*` since it translates to 'every one minute') might cause issues, but it probabl doesn't cause this one.

For more information, see [Timer trigger for Azure Functions - NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions).

> Azure Functions uses the [NCronTab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library to interpret NCRONTAB expressions. An NCRONTAB expression is similar to a CRON expression except that it includes an additional sixth field at the beginning to use for time precision in seconds:
>
> `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`
>
> Each field can have one of the following types of values:
>
> | Type | Example | When triggered |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A specific value | `0 5 * * * *` | Once every hour of the day at minute 5 of each hour |
> | All values (`*`) | `0 * 5 * * *` | At every minute in the hour, during hour 5 |
> | A range (`-` operator) | `5-7 * * * * *` | Three times a minute - at seconds 5 through 7 during every minute of every hour of each day |
> | A set of values (`,` operator) | `5,8,10 * * * * *` | Three times a minute - at seconds 5, 8, and 10 during every minute of every hour of each day > |
> | An interval value (`/` operator) | `0 */5 * * * *` | 12 times an hour - at second 0 of every 5th minute of every hour of each day |

Comment: It doesn't look like an Storage Emulator issue as the function works perfectly with this every 30 second expression "*/30 * * * * *". The error occurs when I try to run the function every minute. Also I am using Visual Studio 2022 which comes with Azurite and my local.settings.json is configured to UseDevelopmentStorage.